# Polynomial evaluated on a Normal Bounded Linear Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let X be a complex Hilbert Space and A be a Normal Bounded Linear Operator.

Show that the radius of the spectrum of A is equal to the norm of A.

Deduce that if P is a polynomial, then the norm of P(A) is equal to the supremum, over complex numbers z in the spectrum of A, of |P(z)|.

I can do the first, but not the second part of this question !! Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is a polynomial, then $P(A)$ is normal, assuming $A$ is normal. Therefore, $\|P(A)\| = r_{\sigma}(P(A))$ is the spectral radius of $P(A)$. But the spectrum of $P(A)$ is $P(\sigma(A))$ by the spectral mapping theorem. Therefore,
$$
     \|P(A)\|=\sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)}|P(\lambda)|.
$$

Comment: Could I ask you a question? What if $P$ is not a polynomial, but a function from the disk algebra? Can we also just say that $P(A)$ is normal if $A$ is normal? Because my Prof told me to use the spectral theorem in this case (or a construction from the continuous functional calculus), so it doesn't seem to be that "obvious" for functions from the disk algebra

Comment: @anon What is your definition of the disk algebra?